# How to use DATEADD(SQL) in DataView Rowfilter? (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, dataview, rowfilter

I`m making program to display information using DataGridView and ComboBox Selection.

In SQL, query is

```
SELECT ListID, ListTitle, ListLastModifyDate  WHERE ListLastModifyDate <= DATEADD(MM, -1, GETDATE())
```

I already built a code.

- Write a text in Text Box, then Click Start Button.
- Matched data showed in DataGridView

And now I want to add this..

- If I choose item in Combobox, selected item`s result showed in DatagridView
- I want to show data without change datasource

So I tried to use DataView`s RowFilter.. but some error found.

Code is  below

```
private void mtcbSiteColSearchCondition_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dvSiteCol = new DataView(dtSiteCol);

        if (mtcbSiteColSearchCondition.SelectedItem.ToString() == "all")
        {
            mgrdSiteCollections.DataSource = dtSiteCol;
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime lastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            dvSiteCol.RowFilter = string.Format("SiteColLastModifyDate <= {0}",lastModifiedDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), mtcbSiteColSearchCondition.SelectedItem.ToString());
            mgrdSiteCollections.DataSource = dvSiteCol;
        }
    }
```

I`m not sure what is right...

Please somebody help me how can I change that query...

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Dateadd is a product specific function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules to use when applying a RowFilter are listed in the [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the DataColumn object.

In particular when filtering on a DateTime value you should enclose your Date value inside the # symbol and express your date in the Invariant culture format

So you should write

```
  dvSiteCol.RowFilter = string.Format("SiteColLastModifyDate <= #{0}#",
                                      lastModifiedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

It is no clear what do you want to do with this part of your code. It is not needed in the format expression, so you should remove this:  `,mtcbSiteColSearchCondition.SelectedItem.ToString());`

Comment: Thank you Steve. Your code works well!!
And I found another solution. 
In Store Procedure, add like this
[SiteColLastModifyDate, DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE()) as modifiedDate] 
and code behind : [dvSiteCol.RowFilter = string.Format("SiteColLastModifyDate <= modifiedDate ");]